# associative array: define the undefined?

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, associative-array

I just tried the following code (in javascript) which should return 'This is totally undefined' which did not work:

```
 var foo = {'foo' : 'bar', undefined : 'This is totally undefined!'};
 alert( foo['toomany foobars'.match(/asdf/)] );
```

yet this works perfectly:

```
 var foo = {'foo' : 'bar', undefined : 'This is totally undefined!'};
 alert(foo[undefined]);
```

I don't understand, is there someone who can explain?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

```
'toomany foobars'.match(/asdf/) === null
null !== undefined
```

Now, on the other hand, if you had this

```
var foo = {'foo' : 'bar', undefined : 'This is totally undefined!', null: 'and this one is null'};
alert( foo['toomany foobars'.match(/asdf/)] );
```

You'd see it working.

---

The reason this happens is that `undefined` is a value in JavaScript, and `null` is another value. When you use these two in dictionary lookups, they will return (and should return) different results.

Comment: I just tried defining null, and it returned 'This is totally undefined', thanks! ... and sorry that I didn't think of that myself